# How to Hide or Remove Zero values in line series Chart in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm using Radchart,i want to remove the line series which is showing value zero.Is there any possible way to hide or remove the value showing zero.Please provide any solution or code.
Now my chart is looking like this.[image]

I need to show image like this.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your question's is repeating over stackoverflow.
I think you need to visit this [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599897/how-to-hide-or-remove-zero-values-in-line-series-radchart)

Comment: Hi,that i am using asp.net controls only.I am not using telerik or other controls.Make sure I am developing application in asp.net